# Breakpad test example error on Linux

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc, google-breakpad

From this [page](http://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/wiki/LinuxStarterGuide#Building_the_Breakpad_libraries) on Google Breakpad to test brekpad example

I am create a simple project like this:

```
#include "client/linux/handler/exception_handler.h"

int main(){
   return 0;
}
```

And prior to that include the header file destination as:

```
C_INCLUDE_PATH=$HOME/breakpad/src

export C_INCLUDE_PATH
```

And then compile it simply with:

```
gcc main.c -o main
```

But my code fails to find exception_handler. To be precise, it gives me this:

```
/home/ubuntu/breakpad/src/client/linux/handler/exception_handler.h:33:18: fatal error: string: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Why is that?

Comment: It looks like it found exception_handler.h, but in it, on line 33, it is not happy about something called "string". If that is another #include, you may need to modify your include path and how you include exception_handler.h.

Comment: I think that include file may be C++. Try changing the name of your file from main.c to main.cpp and recompile. gcc will recognize the .cpp extension as a C++ file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google BreakPad uses C++ inside. Check this link if you want to use it in tandem with C:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-breakpad-discuss/tltR5LJAKlE